# maximum number of comparisons for merging a list of length 5 and a list of length 6

Tags: mergesort

I'm stuck on this question: What is the maximum number of comparisons for merging a list of length 5 and a list of length 6? Write down 2 lists where this maximum number is needed and 2 which can be merged using fewer comparisons. Find an upper bound for the number of comparisons for sorting 11 items using MERGESORT.
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Looks like homework. Think about two completely different lists. Then think about two equal lists.